# Codeigniter valid_ip() not validating localhost's IP

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I am working on localhost(XAMPP) with codeigniter 2.1.0, I just modified welcome_message view with the following code:

```
<p>your IP address:
        <?php
            echo $this->input->ip_address();
            if(!$this->input->valid_ip($this->input->ip_address()))
                echo ' is not a valid IP';
        ?>
    </p>
```

It outputs the following in welcome message:

```
your IP address: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP
```

I think it must return:

```
your IP address: 127.0.0.1
```

but it is not happening this way, why?

Comment: what address you get when you `echo $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’]` instead pf `$this->input->ip_address();`?

Comment: I am getting ::1 as output, (double colons before 1)

Comment: I believe this is answer to your question http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/205222/ you get IPv6

Comment: Thanks Kokers, yes that was the problem, why don't you post your comment as an answer to this question?

Comment: I posted the answer, so everyone could know it's solved. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is answer to your question [ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/205222](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/205222) you get IPv6